# How to append data to existing Dropbox file?

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I'm accessing Dropbox API to upload and download files using Java. Now, I need to create a function which can append data to existing Dropbox file.
I've a working code which first downloads a file and then uploads it with the text appended. However, is there is a better way to do this, because my code has is inefficient?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally there is no support for direct file editing in Dropbox, so what you looking for is not supported in existing APIs of Dropbox, possibly what you are doing currently,

> **first downloads a file and then uploads it with the text appended**

is the best (and the only) way of modifying files in Dropbox cloud.

But apart from this it does support file revision mechanism, which can be achieved with help of /delta, /revision

> A way of letting you keep up with changes to files and folders in a
>   user's Dropbox. You can periodically call /delta to get a list of
>   "delta entries", which are instructions on how to update your local
>   state to match the server's state.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#revisions

Best Luck :)

Comment: This answer is no longer up to date with v2.