# How to append data to existing Dropbox file? (API v2)

Tags: android, dropbox

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672917/how-to-append-data-to-existing-dropbox-file?answertab=oldest#tab-top) has already been asked before, but it related to API v1. If this feature does not available in the new API, then what can you advise? Downloading + modifying + overwriting => is ineffective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox API v2 doesn't offer a way to append data to existing files without re-uploading the entire file. We'll consider it a feature request.